# Why do I get the error 'Invalid range " B->" in transliteration operator' even though `tr` doesn't appear in my code?

Tags: perl, transliteration

I'm getting the following error when I run my Perl script:

> Invalid range "B->" in transliteration operator at ./foo.pl line 249

However, line 249 is commented out, and I don't use the transliteration operator `tr` anywhere in my code.

Here is the relevant piece of my script. Line 249 is `# foreach (@projects)`, and as you can see, it has been commented out.

```
# Find the project name, hardware, and version from the archive given
$project = undef;
$hardware = undef;
$version = undef;
if (defined $testfarmDB){
    my $idFile = `pwd`; 
    chomp $idFile;
    $idFile .= "/$ENV{TESTDIR}/testrun.id";
    y @filecontent = `cat $idFile`;
    $filecontent[0] =~ /(\d+)/;
    my $testRunID = $1;
    $hardware = $testfarmDB->getTestRunModelName($testRunID);
    $project = $testfarmDB->getTestRunProjectName2($testRunID);
    $version = $testfarmDB->getTestRunSWRevisionName($testRunID);
}else{
    die "Cannot connect to Database. Program terminated. \n";
}
print "   Project = $project\n";
print "   Model Type = $hardware\n";
print "   Software Version = $version\n";

# Break up the path given to determine the project and version number
# foreach (@projects)
# {
#     if ($archive =~ /($_)/i)
#     {
#         $project = $_;

#         foreach my $hw (@hardwares)
#         {
#             if ($archive =~ /$hw/i)
#             {
#                 $hardware = $hw;
#                 last;
#             }
#         }
#         last;
#     }
# }

 $archive =~ /((?:\d+\.)+\w+)/;
# $version = $1;
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: We need to see at least the line in question. Please include it, or better yet the surrounding lines as well. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: You probably have a single `/` or a `tr` without anything after it somewhere above that line in your code. It's likely just a typo. But we need to see the code to know for sure.

Comment: @simbabque please take a look at it, I updated it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
 y @filecontent = `cat $idFile`;
```

`y` is an archaic synonym for the `tr` operator. Perl is searching for two more `@` characters to complete the `y@...@...@` statement, and it finds the second one in your comment section.

Comment: There is no way in a million man hours that anybody could have found this without seeing the code.

Comment: Thx much. That was a typo. I didn't want it ever, nor I noticed it.

Comment: @simbabque it's weird that I looked at this code for half day and found nothing

Comment: @Henry that's one of those super obvious typos that every one else spots immediately, but the longer you look the harder it will be to find it. Don't worry about it and move on. Sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes. Happens to everyone. :)